# How to add Announcement list/webpart to Publishing Portal

Tags: list, sharepoint

I have a Publishing Portal site and I need to add some announcements to some of the pages.  I've read an article which says that i have to create an announcement list to be able add an announcement web part but i can't seem to find any resources on how i can add an announcement list.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the home page of your site (or from any page really) you should see a "View All Site Content" link on the top of the navigation menu.

[View All Site Content http://friendfeed.s3.amazonaws.com/86fed07f0809beefaeeaee0013ee2b952079bc09](http://friendfeed.s3.amazonaws.com/86fed07f0809beefaeeaee0013ee2b952079bc09)

Click on that link and it will show you a dashboard listing all of the SharePoint lists that have been provisioned for the current site.  Click on the Create button to create a new SharePoint list.

[Create new SharePoint List http://friendfeed.s3.amazonaws.com/6c0b244801826f8b3ee01811211b88668ba8f713](http://friendfeed.s3.amazonaws.com/6c0b244801826f8b3ee01811211b88668ba8f713)

From there you will see the option to create an Announcments list (under the Communications header).  Complete the wizard to complete the list.

Once the list is created you can select Edit Page from the Site Actions menu on any SharePoint page in the site and then select a "Add a Web Part" on the web part zone you want to put your Announcements web part into.  You should now see a web part listed with the same name as your Announcements list that you just created.

Select that web part to add it to the page and display.

Hope that helps.  If this isn't the answer to your problem leave a comment or update your question with clarification and I will try to help.

Comment: There's no Communications header in my Publishing Portal site. Team site has it though.

Comment: Interesting, I see it on my publishing site.  I'm trying to figure out how that list type might be disabled.  Which feature needs to be enabled or installed.

Comment: This would be a lot of help if I can have it appear on my Publishing Site.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you have not activated the relevant feature on the site settings page. You need to go to the site collection site settings page. Then select Site Actions - manage site features

Then activate the feature called Team Collaboration lists. You will now be able to create an announcement list

Answer (score 1):

Giving you direct instructions on how to create the list would most likely leave you more lost than ever. If this is a publishing portal, there's a lot more to learn beyond just creating a list. Content must be approved, and is versioned. I'd strongy advise you not to start poking around in there as you run a large risk of messing up the portal. Don't get stressed by people demanding you perform such things without having received any training. Grab yourself a coffee, flip your boss the finger and watch some pertinant webcasts on http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/FX101211721033.aspx

Hope this helps,

Oisin